# How PendingIntent triggers intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

For example, we have.

```
PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, FLAG);
```

When we pass our `pi` object to other class or other application, we know that intent wrapped in `pi` will be triggered later by that class or app Right?

I don't understand How it will be triggered?

When we use intent to start component manually/immediately, we call the method corresponding to exact component type (`startActivity(intent), startService(intent)`, etc.) and as I know there is no such method like `startAnyComponent(intent).`

Thanks for your help.

**P.S.**
I guess that there can be an easy way by checking Class objects when the intent is explicit

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz):
```

In such case system can check if `clazz.isAssignableFrom(Service.class)` and call `startService(intent).`

But for implicit intents, I cannot realize what's going on.

Comment: Lemme rephrase that, actually. I'm sure it wasn't clear. What are you asking, exactly? Are you asking how the eventual `Intent` sender knows which `PendingIntent` type it is, and therefore which `start*()`/`send*()` method to use?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I am asking exacly that

Comment: Well, when you call a particular method, the returned `PendingIntent` is configured for that particular component type. That is, it has a flag set internally that is checked before the `Intent` is fired. E.g., when calling `getActivity()`, [the flag is set to `ActivityManager.INTENT_SENDER_ACTIVITY`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#352); `getBroadcast()`, [it's `ActivityManager.INTENT_SENDER_BROADCAST`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#573), etc

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a `PendingIntent`, you call either `getActivity()`, `getBroadcast()` or `getService()`. When the `PendingIntent` is created, the type of `Intent` is included in the `PendingIntent` so that it knows if the `Intent` is for an `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`.

Later, when the `PendingIntent` is used, a call is made to get an `IntentSender` from the `PendingIntent`. To actually send the `Intent`, `IntentSender.sendIntent()` is called. The `IntentSender` knows how the `PendingIntent` was created and therefore knows whether it should use `startActivity()`, `sendBroadcast()` or `startService()` to properly send the `Intent`.

**NOTE:**

Regarding your assumption about how this could work using explicit `Intent`s: This can't work, because usually the app that is actually sending the `Intent` doesn't have access to your app's code and therefore cannot load your classes and can't use `Class.isAssignableFrom()` to determine the type of `Intent`.